# Finding a probability mass function of joint discrete rv

Tags: probability

> You choose three different numbers at random from the numbers
> $1,2,...,10$. Let $X$ be the smallest of these three numbers and $Y$
> be the largest. What is the joint density mass of $X$ and $Y$? What
> are the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$? What is the probability
> mass functions of $Y-X$?

### Try.

We need to find $P(X=x,Y=y)$, to pick the largest and smallest number we do it in one way only, but to pick the third number, it has to be between $x$ and $y$ no inclusive, so all posible values for the third number is ${y-x-1 \choose 1}$. Threfore,

$$ P(X=x,Y=y) = \frac{ {y-x-1 \choose 1} }{ {10 \choose 3 } } = \frac{y-x-1 }{120} $$

Now, $x$ can't be 10 so $x=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ and $y=x+1,x+2,...,10$. So,

$$ p_X(x) = \sum_{y=x+1}^{10}  \frac{y-x-1 }{120} $$

$$ p_Y(y) = \sum_{x=1}^{y-1}\frac{y-x-1 }{120} $$

$$ p_{Y-X}(n) = P(X=x, Y-X=n) = P(X=x, Y=x+n) = \frac{n-1}{120} $$

is this correct?

Comment: You can simplify the sums to $p_x(x) = \dfrac{(9-x)(10-x)}{2}$ and $p_y(y) = \dfrac{(y-1)(y-2)}{2}$ on these ten values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x$ can't be $10$ or $9$ and $y=x+2 , \ldots, 10$

$$p_X(x) =\sum_{y=x+2}^{10}\frac{y-x-1}{120}$$

$$p_Y(y) =\sum_{x=1}^{y-2}\frac{y-x-1}{120}$$

If $n=2, \ldots, 8$, 
\begin{align}
p_{Y-X}(n) &= \sum_{x=1}^{10-n} Pr(X=x,Y=x+n)\\
&= \sum_{x=1}^{10-n} \frac{n-1}{120}\\
&= \frac{(10-n)(n-1)}{120}
\end{align}

Comment: for the  mass fn $Y-X$, why do we need to add the probabilities of the joint of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: $Pr(Y-X=n) = \sum_{x=1}^{10-n}Pr(Y-X=n|X=x)Pr(X=x)$ is the law of total probability.

Comment: but you havent multiplied the left hand side by $P(X=x)$

Comment: $Pr(Y-X=n) = \sum_{x=1}^{10-n}Pr(Y-X=n|X=x)Pr(X=x) =  \sum_{x=1}^{10-n}Pr(Y-X=n,X=x)$

Comment: In law of total probability, we condition on a variable and sum things up

Comment: Sorry to bother, but I am having hard time following this line of reasoning. How does the $P(X=x)$ dissapear ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85301/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-jimmy-sabater).